# How to reduce time for Gradle up-to-date check with a large number of inputs?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to work with the following task to speed it up checking for changes to inputs, but I'm not sure of the best approach:

```
// Create a fatjar(all dependencies included) for use in hadoop jobs
task hadoopJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: jar) {
    from {
        configurations.runtime.collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
    from sourceSets.main.output
    classifier "hadoop"
    extension "jar"
}
```

If I do the following in `build.gradle`, thousands of .class files will be printed:

`println "hadoopJar inputs: "
println hadoopJar.getInputs().getFiles().each() {println "${it}" };`

Checking all of these seems to take about 3 minutes:

```
Skipping task ':jar' as it is up-to-date (took 0.035 secs).
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:jar (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.04 secs.
:hadoopJar (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) started.
:hadoopJar
Skipping task ':hadoopJar' as it is up-to-date (took 3 mins 8.763 secs).
:hadoopJar UP-TO-DATE
:hadoopJar (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 3 mins 8.802 secs.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

While I can't succinctly show the whole example, here is a [link to the state of the code at this time](https://github.com/granthenke/spark-demo/tree/e73e841b6a9cf97a8f80d37baefe104b273d9bca), and I'll be happy to update this post with additional info.

Perhaps the best solution is just to add in a way to [manually skip the task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#14.8)?

Comment: For now I did end up using the skip task method, which is certainly a big help in practice.